# How to store 10000 character string in a Column ,Does ADF reads it or truncates it in Dataflow in the sink

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a column called Notes Where user will enter their long notes which can go greater than 10000 characters ,they store it in col, in csv .

If I read that file in Dataflow and sink to blob as csv as Sql doesnot support more than 8000 characters .

Will it sink or truncate the column to its limit because i want to know the limit .

Comment: Besides ,if i want to load it to sql sever ,there is varbinary datatype that can store this,but at Adf side what can i give as data type if i want to load it to Sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataflow is converted to Spark at runtime. Spark implements a StringType, which has no limit defined. So as long as both the underlying source and sink dataset 's linked services support sizes greater than 8000, Dataflow should be able to handle the full size in both Source and Sink.

Likewise, Copy activity uses the same Datasets. Schemas are optional in Datasets, and even if you do define one, it also uses a generic String type with no size limit.

In other words, if you are reading a text file and writing to a text file, there is effectively no limit and there should be no truncation.

NOTE: if you later try to query this file in a SQL-based system, like Synapse Serverless SQL or SQL Polybase, it will fail on the first row that contains column data over 8000.